# How to enable any user login to my application as a Facebook page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hi I have rails application in which I have implemented facebook connectivity. User can sign in/sign up via Facebook account.
Also when users updates status in my application it automatically gets posted to user's facebook wall.
I want to implement login via facebook page in my application so that when users updates his status in my application it also gets posted to his page & not on his wall.
please guide me how to do this. Thanks in advance!!!